# SparklyR installation issues ("Lazy loading failed")

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio-server, sparklyr

Having some issues installing SparklyR on a Linux server using the same code that has been working smoothly up until yesterday. Have tried it with various combinations of DBI, jsonlite and dplyr installed/ uninstalled.

Everything seems to be running great up until this point:

```
* installing *source* package ‘sparklyr’ ...
** package ‘sparklyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘jsonlite’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘DBI’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
Error in conformMethod(signature, mnames, fnames, f, fdef, definition) :
in method for ‘sqlParseVariables’ with signature ‘conn="spark_connection"’: formal arguments (conn = "spark_connection", sql = "spark_connection", ... = "spark_connection") omitted in the method definition cannot be in the signature
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘sparklyr’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘sparklyr’
```

Not sure if this has something to do with the [GitHub commit on March 8](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/commit/24643429a8ba5196ff8ded9723f6e51c28ac9d4e#diff-35ba4a2677442e210c23a00a5601aba3), but loading the earlier version does not seem to help either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been addressed on the [SparklyR GitHub page](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/538):

> [...] a patch to sparklyr with version 0.5.3 was submitted and accepted to
>   CRAN today, it might take a day to fully replicate in CRAN but for
>   most users, a retry should fix this issue. This was caused by a
>   breaking change in DBI 0.6.

**EDIT 2017-03-10:** Can confirm that new patch is working.